# Can't access cutom file in U-SQL code-behind using custom assemblies?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am registering and using custom assemblies in U-SQL that access a file to fetch data from. The data file is uploaded as an "Addition File" when registering the assembly with it's dependencies (I am using VS 2015).

However, the job fails with a System.IO.FileNotFoundException, with the custom assembly not being able find the file. The exception is raised in the method that accesses the file.

Is there a specific way to access the file? Or does it have to be placed in a specific location?

The file is placed in the same directory as the custom assembly and it's dependencies in the data lake store, if that's a relevant detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
The following script was being auto-generated by Visual Studio when I was registering the assembly:

```
USE DATABASE [master];
DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS  [MaxMind.Db];
CREATE ASSEMBLY [MaxMind.Db] FROM @"swebhdfs://exploreadls.azuredatalakestore.net/assemblies/MaxMind.Db.dll"
WITH ADDITIONAL_FILES = (@"swebhdfs://exploreadls.azuredatalakestore.net/assemblies/GeoLite2-City.mmdb" AS "GeoLite2-City");
```

Notice that the the second file is registered AS "GeoLite2-City" without the ".mmdb" extension, and the assembly accesses the file with the full qualified name.

I had to change this script and re-run it, it worked perfectly after that.

You can view the jobs submitted by Visual Studio through the portal by going to your ADLS account and selecting "View All Jobs"->"View Script" and can "Duplicate Script" to use it for another job.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue :).

Now my question is why the extension was missing. Did you forget when entering the file name originally or was the auto-generation dropping it?

Comment: The auto generation was dropping it.
As you can see at the end of the swebhdfs link, the file name has the extension included, but it isn't there after the AS clause.

Comment: Let me forward your thread to the owners of the tool to look into it.